# Printing Bold in javax.print

Tags: java, printing, javax

I want to print the whole text in bold or change the font size. Is there a way to do this?

```
private void print(String txt, String printerName) {
    PrintService printService[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, pras);
    PrintService service = findPrintService(printerName, printService);

    try {
        DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = txt.getBytes("UTF-8");

        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);

        job.print(doc, null);

        //byte[] cutP = new byte[] { 0x1d, 'V', 1 };
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could wrap the text in `<html><b>...</b></html>` and use a `text/html` based mime type

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for the response, but it won't work!

Comment: It "won't" or "didn't"? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer didn't, sorry for the confusion